# How applyForce figures in with velocity in Corona/Box2d

Tags: box2d, game-physics, coronasdk

Right now i am stuck trying to figure out the trajectory for a projectile. I'm thinking the issue is that i have the wrong velocity. Right now i am using what i pass into applyForce as my velocity, but i'm thinking mass must figure into it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure the velocity is do some reverse checking...

You make a enterFrame event, then you track the last time, last position, new time and new position, see the delta of that, and calculate.

If you projectile does not change direction a lot, you can get more precision by using the median of that data over a long time...

But now a more direct reply to your question is: yes, mass does figure into it... Box2D simulates real world physics, including the law of newton that states that acceleration is proportional to a force applied to a mass, thus acceleration is force multiplied by mass.

Velocity is what acceleration do later.

So if you are applying a force of 10 in a object of mass 10, you get acceleration of 1, in the first frame you have velocity 0, in the second frame velocity of 1, in the third velocity of 2, and so on. Then if you change the force to 20 in the frame 8, you have velocity 7 in that frame, but in the next you will have velocity 9, 11, 13, etc...